# Soap WS-Security error: Incorrect security header

Tags: php, soap, ws-security

I'm try to connect to a web service with WS-Security, but I receive an error message "Incorrect security header", here is the SoapHeader:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken Id="ABC-123">
      <wsse:Username>*****</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>*****</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

And here is the Php code to connect:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("https://www.weservice.com/service?wsdl");

//Body of the Soap Header. 
$headerbody = array("UsernameToken" => array("Username" => "******",
                                             "Password" => "******"));

//Create Soap Header.        
$header = new SoapHeader("wsse", "Security", $headerbody);

//set the Headers of Soap Client. 
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

try{
$result = $client->__soapCall("sendBill", array("fileName" => "filename",
                                                "contentFile" => "byteArray"));

}catch(SoapFault $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the wsdl . Then we can verify that the XML you have provided will/will not match. If the wsdl is large, just the Policy sections will do.

Comment: Thanks muttonUp, however, I can solve this using NuSoap library. But this  bring me a new problem: in the call section "contentFile" I should send a "byte[ ]", I have it but is like it was not recognised ... can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this incident taking a different way.
With Php, the zip file in byte array couldn't be sent because some rare reason (maybe the Php's poor support on attachments over soap protocol).

So I changed the language to C#, now I could test a dummy file to the soap service, I had some (solved) problems, but I receive a succesfull response from the service.